Rails Importmap in Production Loading Incorrect JavaScript Files (MIME type “text/html”)
I’m using Rails 7 with importmaps to manage JavaScript modules. My app works fine in development, but in production, some JavaScript files are failing to load with the following error in the console:
Loading module from “https://example.com/assets/channels/chat_channel” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).
Loading failed for the module with source “https://example.com/assets/controllers/application”.

In production, the correct URLs for these modules should be fingerprinted (e.g., https://example.com/assets/channels/chat_channel-<>digest<>.js), but the browser is trying to load them without the digest, which doesn’t exist, resulting in a 404 error and loading the HTML 404 page instead.
My importmap in the rendered HTML is correctly pointing to the fingerprinted paths. However, the browser keeps attempting to load unfingerprinted URLs.
Solution Attempts:
•   Ensured assets are precompiled.
•   Verified importmap in HTML has the correct URLs.
•   Verified my server serves the correct MIME types for .js files.


The issue is caused by the use of relative paths in the import statements. When you use relative paths (e.g., import consumer from "./consumer"), the browser interprets these paths based on the file system, bypassing the importmap entirely. This causes the browser to look for non-fingerprinted asset paths, which do not exist in production, leading to 404 errors and MIME type issues.
To resolve this, you need to change your import statements to match the exact module specifiers defined in your importmap. Specifically, avoid relative paths and use module specifiers instead in all your JS files. Here’s how you should update your imports:
Incorrect (using relative paths):
import consumer from "./consumer";
import chatChannel from "./chat_channel";

Correct (using module specifiers):
import consumer from "consumer";
import chatChannel from "channels/chat_channel";

